# Create instance with generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

[EDIT]

I organize my question again,

Models for parameter

```
public class PaymentModel
{   
    ... 
}

public class CCPaymentModel : PaymentModel
{
    ...
}

public class PaypalPaymentModel : PaymentModel
{
    ...
}

public class GooglePaymentModel : PaymentModel
{
    ...
}
```

Interface class

```
public interface IPayment<T> where T : PaymentModel
{
    ...
}
```

Models (get inheritance from IPayment),

```
public class SagePayment
    : IPayment<CreditCardPaymentInfo>
{
    public void MakePayment( CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ) {
        // ...
    }

    public void MakeRefund( CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class GooglePayment
    : IPayment<GooglePaymentModel>
{
    public void MakePayment( GooglePaymentModel paymentInfo ) {
        // ...
    }

    public void MakeRefund( GooglePaymentModel paymentInfo ) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class PaypalPayment
    : IPayment<PayPalPaymentModel>
{...}
```

Controller (Create instance)

```
IPayment<???> paymentProcess; // //Error    1   Using the generic type 'com.WebUI.Models.IPayment<T>' requires 1 type arguments

if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
{
    paymentProcess = new SagePayment(); // it need CCPaymentModel type parameter
}
else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
{
    paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment(); // it need PaypalPaymentModel type parameter
}
else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
{
    paymentProcess = new GooglePayment(); // it need GooglePaymentModel type parameter
}

[EDIT]

public void Charge(string paytype,orderNo){

    IPayment<???> paymentProcess; // //Error    1   Using the generic type 'com.WebUI.Models.IPayment<T>' requires 1 type arguments
    Object payinfo;

    if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new SagePayment(); // <== Error, Can not casting
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return CCPaymentModel type object
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); // it return PaypalPaymentModel type object
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new GooglePayment(); // it return GooglePaymentModel type object
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); 
    }

    paymentProcess.MakePayment(payinfo);
}
```

[image]

[EDIT #2]

With this,

```
public interface IPayment {
}

public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel
{
    void MakePayment(string pickno);
    void makeRefund(T refundInfo);
}
```

I got an error, Error   1   'com.WebUI.Models.IPayment' does not contain a definition for 'MakePayment' and no extension method 'MakePayment' accepting a first argument of type 'Ecom.WebUI.Models.IPayment' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, to avoid that error, I move MakePayment method to upper interface class,

```
public interface IPayment {
    void MakePayment(string pickno);
}

public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel
{
    void makeRefund(T refundInfo);
}
```

**Now, the error is gone, BUT how should I do in makeRefund case?
I can not move to upper interface class because I need generic type parameter.**

Could you help me a little more please?

Comment: You would want to have another `IPayment` interface without the generics from which `IPayment<T>` inherits from. That is: `public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel`.

Comment: You are going to need this method to create the generic type via reflection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx.

Comment: What do you want to create an instance of? IPayment is an interface, so you cannot create an instance of it even after you follow @ChrisSinclair's suggestion...

Comment: @fsimonazzi I want to make SagePayment instance and put it into IPayment type varialble

Comment: @fsimonazzi Seems to me that @Expert already has implementations (`PayPalPament`, `GooglePayment`) and the factory is already managing instantiating them.

Comment: You need to instantiate something that implements IPayment<GooglePayment>. There is no such class in your sample. You cannot instantiate an interface.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair that's not what I read in the question. Subclasses of PaymentModel are intended to be the type parameters for a generic IPayment<T>, not implement that interface. I don't think he's trying to do something fancy as GooglePayment : IPayment<GooglePayment>.

Comment: @fsimonazzi I think @Expert has `GooglePayment`, `PayPalPayment`, etc classes (but not shown here) which implement from `IPayment<GooglePaymentModel>` or `IPayment<PayPalPayment>` respectively.

Comment: @Expertwannabe That was my mistake; I accidentally forgot to have `IPayment<T>` inherit from `IPayment`. Change it to `public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair got it - would have helped to see those classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to have another IPayment interface without the generics from which IPayment inherits from. That is:

```
public interface IPayment
{

}

public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel
{

}
```

EDIT: If you really don't want to have an `IPayment` base interface, then you'd have to treat them as type `object`:

```
object paymentProcess;

if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
{
    paymentProcess = new SagePayment();
}
else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
{
    paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment();
}
else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
{
    paymentProcess = new GooglePayment();
}
```

But that might cost you later; regardless you're going to have to cast to work with the specific implementation types. You're really best using a base interface. You may even use it in a nice way:

```
public interface IPayment
{
    PaymentModel Payment { get; }
}
```

So you can reference and use the `PaymentModel` without *knowing* that it's actually a `GooglePaymentModel` specifically.

EDIT: Based on your comment, you might have something like:

```
public interface IPayment
{
    void MakePayment(string pickno);
}

public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel
{
    void MakeRefund(T refundInfo);
}
```

You could even have a non-generic `MakeRefund` version typed against `PaymentModel` so your calling code might not care if it's a `GooglePayment` or not. (but that could cause other issues if they pass a `PayPalPayment`, so that's up to you)

EDIT: Based on your latest code, you'll want something like this:

```
public interface IPayment
{

}

public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel
{
    void MakePayment(T paymentInfo);
    void MakeRefund(T paymentInfo);
}
```

Your controller/factory would look like:

```
//not sure on the exact signature since you didn't provide it
public IPayment CreatePayment(string paytype)
{
    IPayment paymentProcess = null;

    if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new SagePayment();
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment();
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new GooglePayment();
    }

    return paymentProcess
}
```

Your usage code would *somewhere* have to cast it to the known payment type to use:

```
IPayment untypedPayment = Factory.CreatePayment("PayPal");
IPayment<PayPalPaymentModel> typedPayment = (IPayment<PayPalPaymentModel>)untypedPayment;
typedPayment.MakePayment(new PayPalPaymentModel());

//or alternatively
IPayment untypedPayment = Factory.CreatePayment("PayPal");  
PayPalPayment typedPayment = (PayPalPayment)untypedPayment;
typedPayment.MakeRefund(new PayPalPaymentModel());
```

EDIT: Based on your latest edits, this is what you want. Drive your base IPayment calls against a PaymentModel. Then in the specific implementations you can cast or type-check at runtime:

```
public interface IPayment
{
    void MakePayment(PaymentModel paymentInfo);
    void MakeRefund(PaymentModel paymentInfo);
}

public interface IPayment<T> : IPayment where T : PaymentModel
{

}

public class GooglePayment
    : IPayment<GooglePaymentModel>
{
    public void MakePayment(PaymentModel paymentInfo) {
    GooglePaymentModel googlePayment = (GooglePaymentModel)paymentInfo;
    // ...
    }

    public void MakeRefund(PaymentModel paymentInfo) {
    GooglePaymentModel googlePayment = (GooglePaymentModel)paymentInfo;
    // ...
    }
}
```

Then your `Controller`:

```
public void Charge(string paytype,orderNo){

    IPayment paymentProcess = null;
    PaymentModel payinfo = null;

    if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Credit Card"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new SagePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo);
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^PayPal"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new PayPalPayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo);
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(paytype, "^Google"))
    {
        paymentProcess = new GooglePayment();
        payinfo = getPaymentInfo(paytype, orderNo); 
    }

    paymentProcess.MakePayment(payinfo);
}

public PaymentModel getPaymentInfo(string paytype,orderNo)
{
    //return some payment model
}
```

Comment: I have 2 methods in IPayment now, which class do I need to put the methods in? (void MakePayment(string pickno), void makeRefund(T refundInfo))

Comment: @Expertwannabe Depends if they're strongly typed to the `PaymentModel` or not. `MakePayment` probably can be promoted to the base class, but `makeRefund` wouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I couldn't solve the problem still. Could you review my edited question again please? I rewrite with more codes.

Comment: I edited my question again with new controller code, could you review again please? I'm so sorry for bordering you.

Comment: @Expertwannabe I've added another edit. Also from your code/error/screenshot, you _need_ to have `IPayment<T>` inherit from `IPayment`. See the _very first_ code block in my original answer. Your `IPayment<T>` is _not currently_ inheriting from `IPayment`. You need to fix that.

Comment: Oh my god, I am so sorry asking again, could you review my edited(#2) question again please? I am so sorry for bordering again sir.

Comment: @Expertwannabe I've updated my previous edit, but pretty much the solution was already there. I suggest that since now we've resolved the base assignment of `IPayment` from your original question, that you mark this as answered and make a new, specific question based on your new requirements/issues as this question has gotten out of hand from its original state.

Comment: If I do casting parameter in makeRefund method, the Generic is not necessary anymore.. Thank you for your help.